# String with n letters

Tags: regex, vi

I want to find a string with 5 letters via regular expressions.

I tried it like this:

```
/^.\{5}$
```

But this only gives me Strings with 5 letters from the Start of a line, not all Strings in the text.

What is the Expression to find all 5-letter-words ?

Gruß, Andre

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to find all 5-letter sequences, or just 5-letter words? E.g. `abcdefg` has 5 letters in it, should this be matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\<` and `\>` as word boundaries: `/\v<[a-zA-Z]{5}>`.

The `\v` is [Magic Search](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `^` and `$`, since they anchor the match to the start and end of the line. And if you only want letters, use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `.`.

So `[a-zA-Z]\{5}` will find any string of 5 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[A-Za-z]` instead of dot in your regex.

```
^[A-Za-z]\{5}$
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `$` asserts that we are at the end.

OR

```
\<[A-Za-z]\{5}\>
```

`\<`, `\>` called word boundaries.

Comment: This only finds lines that have exactly 5 letters. He wants to match all 5-letter words anywhere on the line.

Comment: then he needs to use word boundaries `\<[A-Za-z]{5}\>` . @Barmar is there any need to escape the `{` symbol?

Comment: You need to escape the `{5}` unless `\v` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\<` and `\>` to denote the beginning and ending of a word:

`\<[A-Za-z]\{5}\>`

This expression matches 5 letter words everywhere in the line.